# Using box2d with starling

Tags: physics, box2d, actionscript-3, starling

In my game I have a **Main** class in which i am initializing starling framework by passing **Game** class like below

```
myStraling = new Starling(Game , stage);
```

In the game class I have Instances of **Welcome** class and **InGame** class these two classes extends **starling.display.Sprite**.I have a **PhysicsHandling** class seperately. Now i want to make instance of **PhysicsHandling** class  in the InGame class.
The physics handling class does not extend any class because it only does calculations. I have made its some variables public to position starling sprites accordingly.

My question is. Is it the right way to integrate physics in starling **Performance wise** .I mean is there a better way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be alright if you are not using too complex shapes or too much bodies at once. If so you could reduce the `Box2D` frame rate ( lets say the game runs at 60 fps so you can call `Box2D` update on every second frame and double the `ms` )  or play around with  `velocityIterations` and `positionIterations` to maximize performance. I actually used this trick in a game that I'm currently working on ( `Starling` + `Box2D` ) and it increased the frame rate from 30~40 fps to fluid 60 fps :)

I know that [physicseditor](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor) allows you to trace polygon points from images but i personally found the result data too complex for my game.